# How to check if the word is already available in user dictionary?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I need the most simple and elegant way (having the word) to check whether the given word is already available in the user dictionary or not. Word frequency doesn't matter, locale does.

Is there something simpler than querying `ContentResolver` iterating and checking with `cursor.getString(INDEX_WORD).equals(myWord)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a query, which will search for your word in the `UserDictionary`:

```
getContentResolver().query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
     new String[]{UserDictionary.Words._ID, UserDictionary.Words.WORD},
     //Selection
     UserDictionary.Words.WORD +" = ?",
     //Selection args
     new String[]{myWord}, null);
```

Than you can check the `Cursor` :

```
if(cursor.getCount()==0){
     //Word is not in dictionary
}
```